# Difference between 2.5.3 label in name and 2.4.6 heading and label

Tags: accessibility

As you can see in the attached picture, the screen reader does not announce the label name.

Which WCAG guideline is failing?

- 1.3.5 identify input purpose
- 3.3.2 labels or instruction
- 2.5.3 label in the name
- 2.4.6 headings and label

[image]

My understanding on identify input purpose, refers to ensure screen reader should be read out the label name and descriptive text accurately. Example: screen reader should read username edit blank.
For labels and instructions: label name and descriptive text are visible and additional instructions like if field is mandatory then asterisk symbol included and required format such as yyyy-mm-dd.

Can anyone please tell me which guideline is failing here and pls let me know the difference between guideline label in name and headings and label.

what need to be tested for each guideline ?

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you asking how you should report this problem? Whether it should be reported?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question, I am not able to understand !!

Comment: Right now, this question sounds like an exam question. Is this for an exam? Do you want us to answer an exam for you (not what this site is for)? Want confirmation of the answer? What do you think is the correct choice? If not, we need more clarification.

Comment: @LeeJensen I want to know the difference between these 4 guidelines and screen reader does not read out label name so which guideline will select to report a defect.